# Parse JSON to HTML with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to parse this JSON link

*http ://www.mse.mk/FreeMseFeeds/service/FreeMSEFeeds.svc/ticker/JSON/9538ac69-2c99-45ba-bbd4-90931ca0cc7d*

to be same like on this page:

*http ://www.mse.mk/en/*

image: 
http: //tinypic.com/r/1zlyhwo/8

I've tried like this:

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.mse.mk/FreeMseFeeds/service/FreeMSEFeeds.svc/ticker/JSON/9538ac69-2c99-45ba-bbd4-90931ca0cc7d",function(data){
   alert(data[0].name);
});
```

I got this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http:// www.mse.mk/FreeMseFeeds/service/FreeMSEFeeds.svc/ticker/JSON/9538ac69-2c99-45ba-bbd4-90931ca0cc7d.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http: //kristijanz.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any help ?

Comment: You have a CORS issue. Google for Cross Origin Resource Sharing for detailed explanations how to activate CORS or workarounds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a CORS issue - your application calling `www.mse.mk/FreeMseFeeds/service/FreeMSEFeeds.svc/ticker/JSON/9538ac69-2c99-45ba-bbd4-90931ca0cc7d` is not running in the same domain.

If you control the service, you can implement CORS to allow other domain origins.

If you do not, you cannot call this service from your domain.

CORS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing